# Does or will monodroid support async await?

Tags: xamarin.android, async-await

I've written an app in wp7, handling most of the asynchroneous tasks with await. I was asked to look into porting it to Android. Fortunately I have MonoDroid at hand, so I don't have to dust off my Java. But I just realized, I cannot reuse my code, as MonoDroid is up to date until .NET 4.0 which doesn't include the compiler for async.

I've found [this](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-21.html) post from december, saying MonoDroid will have async soon. **Any news as to WHEN?**

Comment: C# async support is part of .NET 4.5, not 4.0.  you question is a little premature, at least until Microsoft release .NET 4.5

Comment: @jcwmoore - async/await is part of C# 5 (being a 'compiler trick' on top of TPL for the most part) and not .NET 4.5 per se.  In particular, you can use it with .NET 4 and Silverlight 5 with the Async CTP, and will likely be able to do so with VS11 Beta once the .NET4/SL5 bits are updated, as per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/03/10277166.aspx

Comment: I guess it will come when Mono 3.0 will be added to Monodroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pinged Miguel on twitter about it, and while it will be coming, it's not there yet (at least as of yesterday, March 3rd :)

https://twitter.com/#!/migueldeicaza/status/176033097555517440

Answer (score 4):

This article describe how to use Mono 2.11 (or later) tools which provide support for async/await keywords.

http://www.fizzylogic.nl/2012/05/04/adding-asyncawait-support-to-your-mono-for-android-projects/